# Regex: Match string which contains any number of letters but limited number of numbers/special characters

Tags: regex, string

I would like to match a string that could be a person's name or business name, like:

```
Bob Stewart
Cool-Cows PTY LTD.
55 Burgers Company
Billy O'Dilly
Tom & John's Paper Supplies
```

Basically they are strings which consist mostly of letters (unlimited letters or whitespaces) and may contain numbers or special characters  (', &, -, etc) but not many of them, so I want to limit the maximum occurrence of these characters/numbers in the string (e.g up to 3 each).

I know how to use quantifier to limit occurrence of character set but it will stop at the first occurrence:
`^[a-zA-Z\s]*[^a-zA-Z]{0,3}`

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: What language are you using for regex? Also include some valid and invalid inputs in question

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
[a-zA-Z\s]|^[^a-zA-Z]{0,3}
```

Comment: Nope that appears to independently match every letter or white space

Answer (score 0):

You cant Match with quantifier in unclearly statement like above.
I have a way possibly yourissue with Javascript:

```
<script>
var str='a,,r,t,';
var myTest=str.replace(/[\w]/g,'');
if(myTest.length<4)
  alert('Valid Text')
else
  alert('InValid Text')
</script>
```

Steps:

- remove Characher Alpha
- count number non-Alpha
- set IF Statement to check

Answer (score 0):

Look for at most 3 specials:

```
^([A-Za-z ]*[^A-Za-z ]){0,3}[A-Za-z ]*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/cQ8SQHr7RG).

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesnt seem to work, what's the startin "(?i)" do?

Comment: @Finn `(?i)` means case insensitive, but it depends on the tool. I've taken that out and (I think) fixed the regex.